# mergesort string method java

Tags: java, static-methods, mergesort

I need help with using merge sort with a string array. I've seen many examples of this with an int array but I need help using a string array. I can only use the .compareTo() method. This is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] nameList = {"John", "Mark", "Amber", "Tony", "Matt", "George", 
    "Will", "Bob", "Paul", "Mary Ellen", "Kate", "Joe", "Fred", "Joe", 
    "Anne", "Amber", "Kimberly", "Kelsey", "Matthew"};

    //print original
    System.out.println("Before sorting the names: ");
    for(String element: nameList)
    System.out.print(element + " ");
    System.out.println("\n");
    //Merge Sort
    System.out.println("After sorting the names: ");
    mergesort(nameList, 0, nameList.length);

}
```

These are my methods:

```
private static void merge(String[] data, int first, int n1, int n2) {
    String[] temp = new String[n1 + n2];
    int copied = 0;
    int copied1 = 0;
    int copied2 = 0;

    while((copied1 < n1) && (copied2 < n2)) {
        if(data[first + copied].compareTo(data[first + n1 + copied2]) < 0)
            temp[copied++] = data[first + (copied1++)];
        else
            temp[copied++] = data[first + n1 +(copied2++)];
    }

    while(copied1 < n1)
        temp[copied++] = data[first + (copied1++)];

    for(int i = 0; i < copied; i++)
        data[first +i] = temp[i];

}


public static void mergesort(String[] data, int first, int n) {
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;

    if(n > 1) {
        n1 = n/2;
        n2 = n-n1;

        mergesort(data, first, n1);
        mergesort(data, first + n1, n2);
    }

    merge(data, first, n1, n2);

    for(String element: data)
        System.out.print(element +" ");
}
```

When I run the program it sorts some of it correctly but over all it is not inorder.

Comment: Can you show us the outpu?

Comment: try to shorten array for test purposes and then debug it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one typo and two forgotten lines. Below is fixed function. Compare it with your one.

```
    private static void merge(String[] data, int first, int n1, int n2)
    {
        String[] temp = new String[n1 + n2];
        int copied = 0;
        int copied1 = 0;
        int copied2 = 0;

        while ((copied1 < n1) && (copied2 < n2))
        {
            if (data[first + copied1].compareTo(data[first + n1 + copied2]) < 0)
                temp[copied++] = data[first + (copied1++)];
            else
                temp[copied++] = data[first + n1 + (copied2++)];
        }

        while (copied1 < n1)
            temp[copied++] = data[first + (copied1++)];
        while (copied2 < n2)
            temp[copied++] = data[first + n1 + (copied2++)];

        for (int i = 0; i < copied; i++)
            data[first + i] = temp[i];

    }
```

Comment: @David - this is array, how did you manage it to change size during execution of that function?))

Comment: The printing for loop in mergesort() needs to be eliminated in favor of simply printing nameList following the mergesort() in main().  Then the output with the above change is correct.  Good job answering, though; I had had a strong urge to just point the original poster to the first result of googling "java mergesort". :)

Comment: Ah.. you about prinitng, yes, you right, it prints unnecessary. I just personally love algorithms, and it was pleasure for me to review and debug this code.

Comment: My next question would be how to print the array. i have it in the recursive method so its printing more than 20 times.
edit: never mind i read that too late.

Comment: Just print it after sorting in your main function as it print it before sorting (using the same code). for(String element: nameList) System.out.print(element + " ");

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution for  String Array[] using Mergesort:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int maxSize = 19;             // array size
  DArray arr;                    // reference to array
  arr = new DArray(maxSize);     // create the array
  String[] nameList = {"John", "Mark", "Amber", "Tony", "Matt", "George", 
            "Will", "Bob", "Paul", "Mary Ellen", "Kate", "Joe", "Fred", "Joe", 
            "Anne", "Amber", "Kimberly", "Kelsey", "Matthew"};

 for (int i=0; i<19; i++)
     {
   arr.insert(nameList[i]);
      }

  arr.display();                 // display items

  arr.mergeSort();               // merge sort the array
                              //search using binary search 
  arr.display();                 // display items again
  }  // end main()
}  // end class MergeSortApp

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class DArray
{
private String[] theArray;          // ref to array theArray of strings
private int nElems;               // number of data items
//-----------------------------------------------------------
public DArray(int max)            // constructor
  {
  theArray = new String[max];      // create array
  nElems = 0;
  }
//-----------------------------------------------------------
public void insert(String st)    // put element into array
  {
  theArray[nElems] = st;      // insert it
  nElems++;                      // increment size
  }
//-----------------------------------------------------------
public void display()             // displays array contents
  {
     for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)    // for each element,
     System.out.print(theArray[j] + " ");  // display it
     System.out.println("");
  }
//-----------------------------------------------------------
public void mergeSort()           // called by main()
  {                              // provides workspace
    String[] workSpace = new String[nElems];
    recMergeSort(workSpace, 0, nElems-1);
  }
//-----------------------------------------------------------
private void recMergeSort(String[] workSpace, int lowerBound,
                                           int upperBound)
  {
  if(lowerBound == upperBound)            // if range is 1,
     return;                              // no use sorting
 else
     {                                    // find midpoint
     int mid = (lowerBound+upperBound) / 2;
                                         // sort low half
    recMergeSort(workSpace, lowerBound, mid);
                                         // sort high half
     recMergeSort(workSpace, mid+1, upperBound);
                                         // merge them
     merge(workSpace, lowerBound, mid+1, upperBound);
     }  // end else
  }  // end recMergeSort()
//-----------------------------------------------------------
private void merge(String[] workSpace, int lowPtr,
                       int highPtr, int upperBound)
  {
    int j = 0;                             // workspace index
    int lowerBound = lowPtr;
    int mid = highPtr-1;
    int n = upperBound-lowerBound+1;       // # of items

    while(lowPtr <= mid && highPtr <= upperBound)
            if(  theArray[highPtr].compareTo(theArray[lowPtr])> 0)
           workSpace[j++] = theArray[lowPtr++];
     else
        workSpace[j++] = theArray[highPtr++];

   while(lowPtr <= mid)
     workSpace[j++] = theArray[lowPtr++];

   while(highPtr <= upperBound)
     workSpace[j++] = theArray[highPtr++];

  for(j=0; j<n; j++)
     theArray[lowerBound+j] = workSpace[j];
  }  // end merge()

}  // end class DArray
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```